# Is the range of arccos(x) arbitrary?

Tags: trigonometry

I understand that when you take the inverse of $f(x)=\cos(x)$, you have to limit the domain to ensure that the inverse is a function. This is limiting the range of the inverse.

I understand, then, why the ranges of $\arcsin(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$ are $[-π/2,π/2]$. However, I do not understand why the range of $\arccos(x)$ is $[0,π]$. Why can’t the range be $[-π,0]$? Is this something mathematicians have arbitrarily decided? Why have they done so?

Comment: As to your last question: Yes. It's just a matter of definition.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I’ve added an extra bit to it. I’d like some insight into *why* [0,π] is a slightly better choice.

Comment: The range should be connected. To have $0$ inside seems also natural enough. And then, well, positive numbers are slightly more natural than negative ones.

Comment: Maybe, because people prefer positive numbers.

Comment: Just like the (real) square root. One specific advantage is that non-negative reals are closed under multiplication, which is useful/convenient for square root, but I think for arccos it's just that positive numbers are (slightly) simpler to think about.